# Is there a widget or code that will allow ios camera access?

Tags: ios, google-chrome, google-app-maker

Google appMaker beginner: It appears that Google appMaker doesn't have a native Widget that supports use of the device camera. I would like to explore the possibility that someone has solved this problem.

Comment: As you said, there is no widget that can help you do that. Nonetheless, it is possible. I've done it myself. Here is an article that should provide you some guidance.... https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

Comment: Thanks for the info. Just what I was hoping existed.

Comment: @Morfinismo is there any way you would be willing/able to share what you did in regards to this? I have started implementing this myself as well, however when I get to the part where my camera view generates within a canvas it is only a static camera view and ends up just taking a blank photo when capturing the image. If need be I can provide the relevant code sections.

Comment: @MarkusMalessa For you, of course! You are a great contributor. I have a small sample app I can share it with you. I'll look for your contact in the appmaker group. Give me some hours cause I'm busy now.